# How to create multiple type of users using google OAuth in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth, signals, django-allauth

**I am working in Django and I am making a school management system where I am giving students and teachers to login and register via google OAuth .**

Here are my models

```
from django.db import models 

class Student(models.Model):
    first= models.CharField(max_length = 100 , blank = False , null = False)
    last = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , blank = False , null = False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    class_studying = models.ForeignKey("SchoolClass")
    ...

class Teacher(models.Model):
    first= models.CharField(max_length = 100 , blank = False , null = False)
    last = models.CharField(max_length = 100 , blank = False , null = False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    classes_teaching = models.ManyToManyField("SchoolClass")
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits =6 , decimal_places = 2)
    ...
```

I am using google Oauth with django-allauth package to register , login users via google OAuth .

Here I only have the ability to create only one type of user via google OAuth using signals . Either I can create a student , or either I can create a teacher . But I want to create a way so that I can register a teacher as well as a student via the same OAuth .
I have tried various ways and applied few logics to figure this out but I am unable to get a full fledge solution .

Signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(post_save , sender = User )
def save_student(sender , instance , created , *args , **kwargs):
    if created : 
        student = Student(user = instance)
        student.save()
        ...
```

I am trying to find out different solutions to figure out this problem but I am unable to create a full fledge solution .

As the user is created. It is saved to database in the User Model . I want to create a related person according to the need.

If a teacher want to create acconut , he should be given some other sort of link or register form via google OAuth and for student a different one . This is also not helping me out.

Any kind of help would be great . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove signal and create your own Authentication flow.

The ideal way is to override the auth method and create your own function. In the auth function we will get user type (student, teacher) and we will create a Student or Teacher based on the user type.

```
class GoogleSocialAuthView(GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = GoogleSocialAuthSerializer

def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    data = (serializer.validated_data['auth_token'])
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The Serilaizer Class:

```
class GoogleSocialAuthSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
auth_token = serializers.CharField()

def validate_auth_token(self, auth_token):
    user_data = google.Google.validate(auth_token)
    try:
        user_data['sub']
    except:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'The token is invalid or expired. Please login again.'
        )

    if user_data['aud'] != os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('oops, who are you?')

    user_id = user_data['sub']
    email = user_data['email']
    provider = 'google'
    name = email.split("@")[0]
    return register_social_user(
        provider=provider, user_id=user_id, email=email, name=name
    )
```

The registration Function:

```
def register_social_user(provider, user_id, email, name):
filtered_user_by_email = BenjiUser.objects.filter(email=email)
data = {}
if filtered_user_by_email.exists():
    if provider == filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider:
        registered_user = authenticate(
            username=name, password=os.environ.get('SOCIAL_SECRET')
        )
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(registered_user)
        data['token'] = str(refresh.access_token)
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=registered_user.username)
        data['user'] = BenjiUserSerializer(instance=user).data
        return data
    else:
        raise AuthenticationFailed(
            detail='Please continue your login using ' + filtered_user_by_email[0].auth_provider)

else:
    user = {
        'username': generate_username(name), 'email': email,
        'password': os.environ.get('SOCIAL_SECRET')
    }
    # TODO: Check user type and based on it create object.
    user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**user)
    user.is_verified = True
    user.save()
    new_user = authenticate(
        username=name, password=os.environ.get('SOCIAL_SECRET')
    )
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(new_user)
    data['token'] = str(refresh.access_token)
    from tenants.serializers import BenjiUserSerializer
    data['user'] = CustomUserSerializer(instance=user).data
    return data
```

Comment: Sir , I have gone to every part of the given code and I have understood it . But there are few problems that I am facing and I am also unable to understand few part . Till now I have used one user only for it.  Q.1 : From where the request will be sent to the ```GoogleSocialAuthView``` , the url from which it needs to be called . Q.2 : what will be in the request which is used by post method . Q.3 : how do we get the auth token in the serializer class . Q.4 : I am getting an error saying "module 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google' has no attribute 'Google' " Please help me with this.

Comment: from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.provider import GoogleProvider
from allauth.socialaccount.providers import google
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken.    
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp
google_auth_provider = SocialApp.objects.get(id = 1)
client_id = google_auth_provider.client_id
social_secret = google_auth_provider.secret. .. These are my imports